# How to use WinNAT for both Hyper-V VMs and Docker containers at the same time

Tags: networking, docker, hyper-v, nat, windows-server-2022

I'm trying to set up a home server to host both VM's and Docker containers.

No issues on the VMs running in Hyper-V part:

1. Create a new internal switch (NatSwitch)
2. Set it's IP configuration:  `New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 10.0.75.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex <ifIndex>`
3. Create the NAT configuration: `New-netNat -Name SharedNat -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/17`
4. Create redirections: `Add-NetNatStaticMapping -NatName $NatName -Protocol TCP -ExternalPort 80 -InternalPort 80 -InternalIPAddress 10.0.75.2 -ExternalIPAddress 0.0.0.0`

I'll state now, that at this point the NAT works as expected, the VM behind it can contact the outside world, and the outside world can only initiate contact with the VM by one of the forwarded ports.

Now I'm trying to set up docker so that I can use it at the same time while still using it's NAT functionality (I'm trying to avoid a "transparent" docker network to avoid polluting my network with containers.)

Please note I've found instructions on Microsoft Website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/setup-nat-network, I'll come back to them later.

Because first I needed to install docker. Following these instructions : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=dockerce#windows-server-1, everything installed, time to go back to the NAT setup instructions from earlier.

Small recap:

- 1 External Hyper-V switch (should not have an impact, but is included for completion's sake)
- 1 Internal Hyper-V Switch configured on 10.0.75.1/24 (with one VM running attached to it with IP 10.0.75.2)
- 1 Nat configured on 10.0.0.0/17

From what I understood, I needed to make docker use IPs for its own NAT network that where in the range of 10.0.76.0/24. This was done by adding `"fixed-cidr":"10.0.76.0/24"` in `C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json`

But then when starting docker, I get the following error message in the event log:

> fatal: failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default network: failed during hnsCallRawResponse: hnsCall failed in Win32: You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network. If joining a domain, go to System in Control Panel to change the computer name and try again. If joining a workgroup, choose another workgroup name. (0x34)

What did I miss?

If this has the potential of having an impact on a solution, I'm planning to have this server be the manager of a docker swarm, with a linux VM joining in to be able to host linux containers.

Comment: I think these posts might help : [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63268519/docker-internal-network-and-external-system-to-be-connected-are-in-same-range-i), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359847/docker-doesnt-use-ip-from-defined-pool-when-creating-new-networks), and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930707/forbid-docker-to-use-specific-network).

Comment: Sadly no, third one is docker compose only, the two first ones, are in relation to integrating the containers to a *physical* network from what i understood of the questions.